# Wordpress: Page over page (withour reloading)

Tags: wordpress

I am building my own theme, and I want something advanced:

What i want is a page with links (already have that, now comes the tricky part). When you click on that link, i would like to have a "page" sliding over the "portfolio page (the page with links)" (not covering it compleatly, or with an exit button so you can close the overlay page, and just return on the protfolio page (without reloading if possible).

I need to put this overlay page in a custom post type.

I have been looking into pop-up widgets, but i don't think that will do the job.
Is there a plug-in for this?

Thank you very much for helping me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like these? You can alter them according to your needs

1. http://codepen.io/shubhra/full/JBChq/
2. http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/GridGallery/
3. http://tympanus.net/Development/3DGridEffect/

Comment: That's exactly what I want! Thank you!